# Fetching from std::queue is CPU intensive in a multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, multithreading, queue, cpu-usage, c++98

Please have a look at the following multithreaded C++ pseudocode.( No C++11 )

```
Mutex mtx;

addToQueueFromManyThreads()
{
    mtx.lock;
    pushTowriteQueue();
    mtx.unLock();
}

run()  
{
   std::string nextMessage = fetchNext();

   while ( !nextMessage.empty()  )
   {
       //  writeToFile( nextMessage );
       //  (void)SchedYield();
       nextMessage = fetchNext();   
    }
    delay( 25 ms );
}


std::string CTraceFileWriterThread::fetchNext() 
{
    std::string message;
 
    mtx.lock;
    if( !writeQueue.empty() )
    {
      message = writeQueue.front();
      writeQueue.pop();
    }
    mtx.unLock();

    return message;
}
```

1. Not much difference with or without 'writeToFile' or 'SchedYield'.
2. I am running on a low priority thread
3. The whole process is being killed due to heavy CPU usage because of the above code
4. addToQueueFromManyThreads is called extensively by the application as there are a lot of messages to be logged every second

At this point, I am wondering if I am using the right data structure and I have tried everything I can and run out of options. Any help with what could be happening is appreciated.

Comment: I note that your `delay()` is outside the while loop in `run()`. That seems like an error. But beyond using a condition variable instead of manually checking, how many threads are you running? How fast is data coming in?

Comment: Please provide compiling code when at all possible.  Pseudo code is much less useful.

Comment: @metal , as a matter of fact I have also tried using a condition variable but the messages are so fast it doesn't really matter. It would get signalled 50-60 times in a second. So, I thought I would simplify and see what is really happening. We have around 40 threads running which are pushing to the queue

Comment: How many processors do you have? 40 threads sounds like a lot of overhead for context switching, which could be making the problem worse rather than giving your more throughput. Condition variables rather than manual yielding could minimize the amount context switching by activating only one waiting thread at a time.

Comment: The machine is old and the processing capability is not huge. I do not have the specifics though.But, just having condition variables is not helping.

Comment: There are piles of problems in your pseudocode, but you have already stated your pseudocode doesn't match your real code (your real code has a condition variable).  I don't see the point of pointing out errors in your pseudo code that may or may not match the actual problem you are experiencing.  A [mcve] is both a simplification **and one that experiences the problem**.  This is a non-functional simplification that may or may not demonstrate your problem, you don't know.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have posted an other question trying best to accommodate the above. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305427/producer-consumer-problem-cpu-intensive-because-of-huge-amount-of-logs

Comment: Have you considered using a lock-free queue instead?

Comment: @mpoeter I do not have C++11. What is your recommendation. Also, I have posted a new question here with the actual code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305427/producer-consumer-problem-cpu-intensive-because-of-huge-amount-of-logs

Answer (score 2):

The logic in `run()` is flawed. It effectively runs non-stop, checking over and over again whether there's a message in the queue to be had. If there isn't, what does it do? It checks again, in faint hope that a new message arrived in the last millisecond, or so. That's why you're driving the CPU load high. The fact that it spends most of the time with a locked mutex, preventing other execution threads, that want to add a new message to the queue, from locking the mutex, does not help either.

The textbook solution to correctly implement this is simply using a condition variable, and waiting on it. Condition variables existed before C++11, and are available in POSIX. This will put the execution thread to sleep, stopping all CPU activity, completely, until the condition variable gets signalled by the other execution thread, after adding a new message to the queue. You cannot fix this without using a condition variable, there are no other practical alternatives.

How to use a condition variable is explained in every C++ textbook that covers execution threads and POSIX, where I will direct you for more information, and examples, especially since the shown code is pseudocode. You should spend some time reviewing this material in order to understand and learn the correct way to use condition variables, and their semantics. Improper usage won't help, and will likely make things worse.

Comment: I'd almost recommend looking at a C++11 condition variable based threadsafe queue.  Translating it back to POSIX should be possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I have already tried using a condition variable but the message inflow is so fast it doesn't really matter. We have around 40 threads to push to the queue in question. As you mentioned, holding the mutex and blocking other threads could be the problem.

Comment: If you are using condition variables correctly the mutex will not be locked and block other threads while `run()` is waiting for a new message.

Comment: You should post a new question. One question per stackoverflow.com question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you mentioned, I have posted a question with the proper code in place  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63305427/producer-consumer-problem-cpu-intensive-because-of-huge-amount-of-logs

Comment: A semaphore is a practical alternative.

Comment: @MartinJames how so? Could you please post a link with an example which could help me with this.

Comment: @abhilashanand you don't need one - it's trivial.  Your producer queues an item and then posts a unit to the semaphore.  Your consumer waits on the semaphore, then dequeues an item. The downside js that you will usually, (the only exception is with one producer, one consumer and a queue class that can safely handle push/pop in that case), need a separate mutex to protect the queue from multiple access.  The upside is that you don't need to check anything else - the receipt of a semaphore unit by a thread guarantees that a item is waiting for that thread.